# How do I get only the latitude and longitude for the 'smallest' zip

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the columns:

- zip
- city
- state
- timezone
- latitude
- longitude
- dst

For the procedure I'm working on I need to return the `city`, `state`, `latitude` and `longitude` based on the `min(zip)` grouped by `city`.  So for the following rows in the table, I'd need the procedure to return the row that has the zip 18101.  This would have to be done for every city in that table.

```
zip     city        state   timezone    latitude    longitude   dst
18106   Allentown   PA      -5          40.56929    -75.58893   1
18195   Allentown   PA      -5          40.57983    -75.57989   1
18175   Allentown   PA      -5          40.58556    -75.62106   1
18103   Allentown   PA      -5          40.5951     -75.45915   1
18104   Allentown   PA      -5          40.602      -75.52104   1
18101   Allentown   PA      -5          40.60285    -75.47022   1
18102   Allentown   PA      -5          40.60775    -75.4793    1
18105   Allentown   PA      -5          40.69337    -75.47115   1
```

Is there another way (more efficient) other than finding the `min(zip)` first grouped by `city` then using that `zip` in a separate select to get the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select z.*
from (select z.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city, state order by zip asc) as seqnum
      from zips z
     ) z
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with a subquery:

```
select city, state, latitude, longitude
from Table A
where zip = (select min(zip) from Table b where a.City = b.City)
```

Edit: Format